# Why should $\phi'$ and $\phi''$ be $\mathcal O(1)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, dimensional-analysis

As Strogatz writes in his book Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos (p. 64)

> There are often several ways to nondimensionalize an equation, and the best choice might not be clear at first. Therefore we proceed in a ﬂexible fashion. We define a dimensionless time $\tau$ by $$\tau = \frac{t}{T}$$ where $T$ is a characteristic time scale to be chosen later. When $T$ is chosen correctly, the new derivatives $d\phi/d\tau$ and $d^2\phi/d\tau^2$ should be $\mathcal O(1)$, i.e., of order unity.

Why should the new derivatives be bounded?

**Added** context: The system he discusses in that section is an overdamped bead on a rotating hoop where $\phi$ is the angle between the bead and the downward vertical direction.

**Added**: as Joriki [writes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/171704/51387)

> The characteristic time is usually defined to be the time in which a quantity decreases by $1/\mathrm e$.

Is this somehow behind the choice of $\mathcal O(1)$?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: @anomaly: I added some context, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: This is the rough definition of "characteristic time scale" - the solution changes significantly ($O(1)$) over a time-scals $\Delta t \sim O(T)$.

Comment: I think the idea is that $\tau$ should be dimensionless, and that this constitutes being $\mathscr{O}(1)$ - see the "nondimensionalize an equation" part. Note that when he says that T is a time scale, it doesn't have to be a constant, it just has to be a monotone increasing function in general.

Comment: It depends what you want to know, there can be more than one time scale in a problem, for example an oscillator with a small damping term has a fast time scale of the period of an oscillation, and a slow time scale, the time over which the amplitude decreases. By rescaling the equation appropriately you can focus on each of these time-scales separately.

Comment: @David: and what exactly makes us choose $O(1)$?

Comment: Related: [What is the general definition of time-scale for a differential equation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460806/what-is-the-general-definition-of-time-scale-for-a-differential-equation)

Comment: In this case $\phi$ is an angle so $O(1)$ consitutes a significant angle change: if $\Delta\phi \ll1$ the angle has not changed much and if $\Delta\phi = \pi$ it has changed the maximum. In a more general context (say if $\phi$ was a temperature or the distance traveled) then $\phi$ would have to be rescaled for us to say that $O(1)$ to be considered a significant change.

Comment: @Leo you want to end up with a dominant balance, and generally we write the largest terms as being $O(1)$, because you can always multiply an equation by a constant to make the largest terms $O(1)$. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546644/find-location-and-width-of-boundary-layer/1546779#1546779) is an example of an ODE with two natural length scales that might show the idea more clearly.

Comment: It's _supposedly_ explained in Strogatz's lecture:
https://youtu.be/eZmzmQW-fAA?t=3075